# Comparing two class types

Tags: c#, .net, types

I am trying to compare two class types, but i keep getting an error.

```
 if (mediaTitleCollection[i].GetType() == Catalog.FilmMedia)
```

I get following error: 'Catalog.FilmMedia' is a 'type' which is not valid in this context.

I dont exactly see the problem hence the primary thing im comparing with is a type aswell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `typeof`:

```
if (mediaTitleColection[i].GetType()==typeof(Catalog.FilmMedia)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `typeof()` this will return a comparible type.

```
if(mediaTitleCollection[i].GetType() == typeof(Catalog.FilmMedia))
```

Or you could maybe use also the [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) operator:

```
if(mediaTitleCollection[i] is Catalog.FilmMedia)
```

Comment: I like the is option personally as it uses less code to achieve the same function.

Answer (score 2):

The is operator is faster and easier to read, so definitely use it.

```
if(mediaTitleCollection[i] is Catalog.FilmMedia)
```

The other thing you could do if you need to cast `mediaTitleCollection[i]` to FilmMedia is:

```
Catalog.FilmMedia filmMedia = mediaTitleCollection[i] as Catalog.FilmMedia;
if (filmMedia != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `typeof(Catalog.FilmMedia)` at the right side of `==`.

Catalog.FilmMedia isn't anything that runtime can compare with - you have to turn it into [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) with [`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the typeof statement

```
if (mediaTitleCollection[i].GetType() == typeof(Catalog.FilmMedia))
```